# Show that $(f|M)(z) := (cz+d)^{-r/2}f(Mz)$ has a weight $r/2$.

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-explanation, modular-forms

The following text is from Complex Analysis by Freitag :
[image]
For $r ∈ \mathbb{Z}$ *the modified Petersson notation* is defined : $$(f|M)(z) := \sqrt{cz+d}^{-r}f(Mz)$$ for $M ∈ SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$.

In the theorem above (Proposition VI.5.11), f is a modular form of weight $r/2$ which means $f(Mz)=(cz+d)^{r/2}f(z)$ so, all $(f|M)(z)$'s must have weight $0$ because $(f|M)(z) = (cz+d)^{-r/2}f(Mz)=(cz+d)^{-r/2}(cz+d)^{r/2}f(z) =f(z).$ So how $(f|M)(z)$ has weight $r/2$ or/and consequently $F = \Pi (f|M)$ weight $kr/2$? Simple clear explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: No. It meant $f^2$ is a modular form of integer weight $r$ and $F^2$ is a modular form of weight $kr$. If $r < 0$ then $\lim_{\Im(z) \to 0} F(z)^2 = 0$ so (Schwartz reflection principle) $F^2$ is entire and bounded thus constant

Comment: @reuns, $F$ is not a product of $f$'s; it's a product of $f|M$'s.

Comment: If $f \in M_k(\Gamma)$ then $f|\gamma \in M_k(\gamma^{-1}\Gamma \gamma)$ (when there are characters and non-integer weights it needs a little more but the idea is there)

Comment: @reuns, Sorry I couldn't understand! Can we analyse my argument in OP so I can know where am I doing wrong, please? I am studying from Freitag's book bc it's the easiest book I've found in MF and I am first year UG student so I will truly appreciate easy explanation.

Comment: $f \in M_k(\Gamma,\chi)$ means for every $\alpha \in \Gamma$ then $f(\alpha(z)) = \pm\chi(\alpha) (cz+d)^k  f(z)$ where $(cz+d)^k = \alpha'(z)^{-k/2}$. With $f_2(z) = f(\gamma (z))$ then $f_2(\alpha(z)) =  \pm \chi(\gamma\alpha\gamma^{-1}) (cz+d)^k  f(z)$ for $\alpha \in \gamma^{-1}\Gamma \gamma$.

Comment: @reuns, $c$ and $d$ comes from 2nd row of $\alpha$, so if we use $γαγ^{−1}$ instead, we need to replace $c$ and $d$ with [21] and [22] -th entries of $γαγ^{−1}$, respectively. I.e. $f_2(\alpha(z)) =  \pm \chi(\gamma\alpha\gamma^{-1}) (c_1z+d_1)^k  f(z)$ in which $c_1$ and $d_1$ are [21] and [22] -th entries of $γαγ^{−1}$ (?)